# Como concatenar dados serializados de um form à string javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenação-de-string, serialização, formdata

Como eu posso concatenar um variável de dados serializada `var dados = $(form).serialize();`
com um segunda variável, por exemplo `var x ="2222"`?

Obrigado pela atenção!
Horácio

Answer (score 1):

Basta pegar o resultado da variável serializada e concatenar com a outra existente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var dados = $("form").serialize();
        var x = "2222";
        
        $("h1").text(dados+"&x="+x);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  Nome: <input type="text" name="name" value="Fulano"><br>
  Idade: <input type="text" name="idade" value="34"><br>
</form>
<br>
<button>Serializar</button>

<h1></h1>
```